# Access Parent Element Within href

Tags: javascript

So... this is a simple question with a simple answer, but somehow my RTFMing isn't proving any results.

I have a link within a div, like so:

`<div> <a href=''>Close</a>`

I'd like to close that div with that link, and I've been trying the following code:

`<div> <a href="javascript:this.parentNode.style.display='none'">Close</a>`

However, it still hasn't worked... any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
<div> <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'">Close</a>
```

The reason is that when using `href="javascript:...`, `this` doesn't refer to the element that received the event.

You need to be in an event handler like `onclick` for that.